# Why calling a dequeue_op in the following code throw tensorflow.python.framework.errors.OutOfRangeError

Tags: tensorflow

In the following example I read a data from file, decode it and create a batch with tf.train.shuffle_batch. I start every queue runner threads and then fetch my batch. It throws outOfRange error as if my data queues are empty. I don't understand why since I start every queue runners.

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(source,shuffle=True)

example, label = decode_and_transform(filename_queue, ....)
examples, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([example, label], ...)

init_var = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_var)
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

# throw out of range error
img, lab = sess.run([examples, labels])
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for an *unexpected* [`tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#OutOfRangeError) is that one of the operations that enqueues elements to the queue has failed. Check whether one of the ops in your `decode_and_transform()` function is failing, by running the upstream code manually (and without calling `tf.train.start_queue_runners()`:

```
# Runs the ops before `tf.train.shuffle_batch()`.
example_val, label_val = sess.run([example, label])
```